# Splitting data and running linear regression loop

Tags: r, loops, regression, lm

I have seen a lot of similar questions, but there is one key to the loop that I am trying to write that I am missing.  I have a a set of dataset with ~4,000 different keys, and for each key, there are ~1,000 observations.  I have filtered out a key to isolate the observations for that key, run linear regression, checked model assumptions and all looks good.  However, I want to loop over this dataset and run that linear regression for each of the keys.  Then I will want to store the coefficients, pvalues, R^2, etc and review them together.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
Key y1 x1 x2
A   10 1  3
A   11 2  4 
A   12 3  5
B   13 4  6 
B   14 5  7
B   15 6  8
C   16 7  9 
C   17 8  1
C   18 9  2
```

I have run:

```
datA <- data %>% filter(key=='A')
lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = datA)
```

And then repeated that for keys B and C. Each question that I have seen on here is looking at the looping over the different variables for the entire set, but not splitting the data on the rows.

But I need to do this 4,000 more times.  Any assistance to write this loop would be greatly appreciated (I am terrible at writing loops).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can also use the **broom** package to tidy the output into a more readable form.

```
list_models <- lapply(split(data, data$Key), function(x) lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = x))

library(broom)

as_tibble(do.call(rbind, lapply(list_models, broom::tidy)))

# A tibble: 7 x 5
  term        estimate  std.error statistic    p.value
  <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
1 (Intercept) 9.00e+ 0   2.22e-15   4.05e15   1.57e-16
2 x1          1.00e+ 0   1.03e-15   9.73e14   6.54e-16
3 (Intercept) 9.00e+ 0   4.59e-15   1.96e15   3.25e-16
4 x1          1.00e+ 0   9.06e-16   1.10e15   5.77e-16
5 (Intercept) 9.00e+ 0 NaN        NaN       NaN       
6 x1          1.00e+ 0 NaN        NaN       NaN       
7 x2          3.02e-16 NaN        NaN       NaN
```

Comment: I am trying lots of different things, but I just don't think my local machine is powerful enough to run this.  I am getting an error:
`Error: cannot allocate vector of size XX.x Mb`  Is this just because my machine is not powerful enough to run 4000 keys with 900+ observations per key, 10+ parameters per key?

Comment: So, I have worked to clean up my memory, and I can get this to run, very quickly by the way, but do you think there is any way to add the Key value into the `term`?

Comment: You have to include it in the model.

Answer (score 3):

You could `split` the data and apply `lm` to each chunk.

```
list_models <- lapply(split(df, df$Key), function(x) lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = x))
```

A `tidyverse` way would be :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list_models <- df %>% group_split(Key) %>% map(~lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = .x))
```

It returns a model for each individual `Key`.

```
list_models
#$A
#Call:
#lm(formula = y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = x)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           x1           x2  
#          9            1           NA  

#$B
#Call:
#lm(formula = y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = x)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           x1           x2  
#          9            1           NA  

#$C
#Call:
#lm(formula = y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = x)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)           x1           x2  
#   9.00e+00     1.00e+00     7.86e-16
```

Comment: This worked great.  Just to followup for anyone interested, I used `list_models_df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, list_models))` to get a nicely formed dataframe with all the model parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Much less elegant than @RonakShah's answer, you can group by your key and summarise for each key while extracting values of interest in order to get the following table:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Key) %>%
  summarise(Intercept = lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2)$coefficients[1],
            Coeff_x1 = lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2)$coefficients[2],
            Coeff_x2 = lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2)$coefficients[3],
            R2 = summary(lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2))$r.squared,
            pvalue = summary(lm(y1 ~ x1 + x2))$coefficients["x1",4])

# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Key   Intercept Coeff_x1  Coeff_x2    R2     pvalue
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A            9.     1.00 NA            1   8.00e-16
2 B            9.     1.00 NA            1   7.00e-16
3 C            9.     1.00  7.86e-16     1 NaN
```

Comment: This actually works really well, as I can pull out the features from the model summary that I want to highlight for the entire set of models.  It does take a little more coding than what @RonakShah but this does work very well.